# Neumann problem on a convex domain

Tags: convexity, laplace-equation

Let $\Omega$ be a convex open bounded subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and let $u$ be the solution of
$$
\begin{cases}
∆ u=1\quad\text{in $\Omega$,}
\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=\frac{\vert \Omega\vert_n}{\vert\partial\Omega\vert_{n-1}}\quad\text{on $\partial\Omega$.}
\end{cases}
$$
Is it true that  $u$ is a convex function?

Comment: Do $|\Omega|_n$ and $|\partial\Omega|_{n-1}$ respectively mean the the volume and the perimeter of $\Omega$?

Comment: Yes, indeed. The constant on the right-hand-side of the normal derivative is forced by Green's formula.

Comment: Thank you very much for your observations pertaining my deleted “answer”. It is hard to be mathematically lucid while dealing with nieces and nephews.